# Show that if $\mu,\eta\in I\implies \dfrac{\mu+\eta}{2}\in I$ and $\{0,1,1/2\}\subset I$ implies $[0,1]\subset I$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, positive-semidefinite, quantum-computation, quantum-information

> Let $R_1,R_2,S_1,S_2,T_1,T_2$ be positive operators such that $[R_1,R_2]=[S_1,S_2]=[T_1,T_2]=0$, and $R_1\ge S_1+T_1$ $,R_2\ge S_2+T_2$ then for all $0\le t\le 1$,
> \begin{align}
> R_1^tR_2^{1-t}\ge S_1^tS_2^{1-t}+T_1^tT_2^{1-t}\tag{A6.8}\label{A6.8}
> \end{align}
> is true as a matrix inequality.

This is given as a Lemma in proving Lieb's theorem, please check my reference, [Equation A6.8, Appendix 6: Proof of Lieb’s theorem, Page 646, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf).

---

Let $I$ be the set of all $t$ such that the equation $R_1^tR_2^{1-t}\ge S_1^tS_2^{1-t}+T_1^tT_2^{1-t}$ holds. Then we can easily prove in few steps that, $0,1/2,1$ are elements of $I$.
ie.,
$$
R_1\ge S_1+T_1\\\\
R_2\ge S_2+T_2\\\\
R_1^{1/2}R_2^{1/2}\ge S_1^{1/2}S_2^{1/2}+T_1^{1/2}T_2^{1/2}
$$

Having done that, suppose $\mu$ and $\eta$ are any two elements of $I$ so that
$$
R_1^\mu R_2^{1-\mu}\ge S_1^\mu S_2^{1-\mu}+T_1^\mu T_2^{1-\mu}\\
R_1^\eta R_2^{1-\eta}\ge S_1^\eta S_2^{1-\eta}+T_1^\eta T_2^{1-\eta}\\
$$
where $R_1^\mu R_2^{1-\mu},S_1^\mu S_2^{1-\mu},T_1^\mu T_2^{1-\mu},R_1^\eta R_2^{1-\eta},S_1^\eta S_2^{1-\eta},T_1^\eta T_2^{1-\eta}$ are positive operators such that $[R_1^\mu R_2^{1-\mu},R_1^\eta R_2^{1-\eta}]=[S_1^\mu S_2^{1-\mu},S_1^\eta S_2^{1-\eta}]=[T_1^\mu T_2^{1-\mu},T_1^\eta T_2^{1-\eta}]=0$

We have already proven the $t=1/2$ case, therefore,
$$
(R_1^\mu R_2^{1-\mu})^{1/2}(R_1^\eta R_2^{1-\eta})^{1/2}\ge (S_1^\mu S_2^{1-\mu})^{1/2}(S_1^\eta S_2^{1-\eta})^{1/2}+(T_1^\mu T_2^{1-\mu})^{1/2}(T_1^\eta T_2^{1-\eta})^{1/2}
$$
Using the commutativity assumptions $[R_1,R_2]=[S_1,S_2]=[T_1,T_2]=0$ and $\nu=\dfrac{\mu+\eta}{2}$,
$$
R_1^\nu R_2^{1-\nu}\ge S_1^\nu S_2^{1-\nu}+T_1^\nu T_2^{1-\nu}
$$
$\implies $ whenever $\mu$ and $\eta$ are in $I$, so is $\dfrac{\mu+\eta}{2}$.

---

This much is fine. But now it went on to say that,

Since $0$ and $1$ are in $I$, it is easy to see that any number $t$ between $0$ and $1$ with a finite binary expansion must be in $I$. Thus $I$ is dense in $[0, 1]$. The result now follows from the continuity in $t$ of the conclusion, (\ref{A6.8}).

How do I justify this?

---

Using the argument whenever $\mu$ and $\eta$ are in $I$, so is $\dfrac{\mu+\eta}{2}$, we can easily show that $1/2,1/4,1/8,\cdots,1/2^n\in I$, similarly infinite number of other elements in $I$, but how do I prove that $t$ spans the entire range $[0,1]$?

What about irrational numbers in the range $[0,1]$?

Comment: I think this is one of those "by a density argument" or "just pass to subsequence" type of things analysts say. We write down the full detail at some point during grad courses and after it just becomes a bit of a folklore-ish stuff. 

The detail is then to pick a $x\in I$ without finite binary expansion and the density tells you that there is a sequence $x_i\to x$, with $x_i\in I.$ So essentially, you are approximating $R_j^{x}$ with $R_j^{x_i}$, which gives you an $\epsilon$-relaxed version of your inequality and then you pass to the limit to get the desired result.

Comment: Please clarify: (1) are the domains of these operators finite-dimensional? (2) In your question, should “$R_1\ge S_1+T_1,\,R_1\ge S_1+T_1$” read “$R_1\ge S_1+T_1,\,\color{red}{R_2\ge S_2+T_2}$”?

Comment: @user1551 Sorry it was a typo, it is $R_1\ge S_1+T_1$ $,R_2\ge S_2+T_2$. And I think these operators are of finite size.

Comment: @dezdichado I have added my attempt section in the posit, is it what you were talking about? But what about numbers in the range $[0,1]$ which do not have a finite binary expansion?

Comment: that's where the density comes in. The detail is that you need to prove the set of numbers you already found to be in $I$ is dense in $[0,1].$ I am guessing this will be just simple as picking an irrational number with infinite binary expansion and define the natural sequence that is truncated at $n$-th term that converges to it.

Comment: look for a proof [dyadic rationals are dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263128/how-can-we-show-that-the-dyadic-rationals-are-dense-in-mathbb-r) for example

Comment: @dezdichado I tried to show that $I$ is dense in $[0,1]$ by adding part 2 in my attempt section in the post. Could you please have a look? But having shown that, is there any more reasoning required to prove $I=[0,1]$?

Comment: @SoorajS, I think the answers in the link seem to provide the full proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Part 1 in my attempt in the post already proves $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\subset I$, right ? In part 2, we can always find a $t_n\in [0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ for all irrational $t\in[0,1]$ such that $t_n$ converges to $t$ at $n\to\infty$. But what is the continuity argument in my reference which proves that an irrational $t\in I$ ?

Comment: In part 1 you have handled rationals with finite binary decimal representations. This does not include rationals like $1/3$ (or any rational with denominator not a power of $2$).

Comment: The irrational $t$ by the way does not lie in $I$.

Comment: I have deleted some of my previous comments as the argument of the answer linked there does not apply fully to current problem. Let $0,1\in I$ and further whenever $\mu, \nu\in I\implies\frac{\mu+\nu} {2}\in I$. Then we can only say that all dyadic rationals of $[0,1]$ lie in $I$. The irrationals as well as non-dyadic rationals of $[0,1]$ may or may not lie in $I$ and we can't infer anything about them. However dyadic rationals being dense in $[0,1]$ will help to prove the main result of your question.

Comment: @dezdichado The proof in the post "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263128/how-can-we-show-that-the-dyadic-rationals-are-dense-in-mathbb-r" proves that $I$ is dense in $[0,1]$, ie., for all $\delta>0$ there exists some $t_n\in I$ such that $|t-t_n|<\delta$ where $t\in [0,1]$. But what is the continuity argument in my reference which proves the result? Is it that, if we take any $t\in[0,1]$ there exists $t_n\in I$ such that $|t-t_n|<\delta$ for all $\delta$, which means there is a continuum of $t\in[0,1]$ that corresponds to $I$, right ?

Comment: That's just sloppy writing. Physicists are notorious for their disregard for pure math rigor and the language. The "continuity" in $t$ is pretty sure to mean you can approach $t$ by a sequence in your already established $I$ i.e., dyadic rationals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1**

A number $t_n\in[0,1]$ with finite binary expansion can be written as
\begin{align}
t_n&=0.\phi_1\phi_2\phi_3\cdots\phi_n=\frac{\phi_1}{2^1}+\frac{\phi_2}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_3}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\phi_n}{2^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\phi_1+\Bigg(\frac{\phi_2}{2^1}+\frac{\phi_3}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_4}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\phi_n}{2^{n-1}}\Bigg)\Bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\phi_1+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\phi_2+\frac{\phi_3}{2^1}+\frac{\phi_4}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_5}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\phi_n}{2^{n-2}}\Bigg)\Bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\phi_1+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\phi_2+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\phi_3+\frac{\phi_4}{2^1}+\frac{\phi_5}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_6}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\phi_n}{2^{n-3}}\bigg)\Bigg)\Bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg[\phi_1+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\phi_2+\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\phi_3+\cdots\phi_{n-3}+\Big(\frac{1}{2}\big(\phi_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})\big)\Big)\bigg)\Bigg)\bigg]\\
\end{align}

where $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,\cdots,\phi_n\in\{0,1\}$

Looking at the inner most term, $\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})$ in which $\phi_{n-1}=0$ or $1$ and $\phi_n/2=0$ or $1/2$, ie., $\phi_{n-1},\phi_n/2\in I$, and therefore $\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})\in I$. In the next term $\frac{1}{2}\big(\phi_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})\big)$ has $\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})\in I$ (as shown in the last step) and $\phi_{n-2}\in I$, and therefore $\frac{1}{2}\big(\phi_{n-2}+\frac{1}{2}(\phi_{n-1}+\frac{\phi_n}{2^1})\big)\in I$. Continuing this way we can prove that any number $t_n=0.\phi_1\phi_2\phi_3\cdots\phi_n=\frac{\phi_1}{2^1}+\frac{\phi_2}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_3}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\phi_n}{2^n}=\frac{k}{2^n}$ with finite binary expansion (dyadic rationals) is a member of I.

---

> Definition: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set that is bounded above. Then a number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is called the supremum (least upper bound) of A, and is denoted by $\sup A$ iff:
>
> - $x\le\alpha$ for all $x\in A$
> - if $y$ is a upper bound for $A$, then $y\ge \alpha$

> The Completeness Axiom: Every nonempty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound. That is,  $\sup A$ exists and is a real number.

> Definition: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set that is bounded below. Then a number $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ is called the infimum (greatest lower bound) of A, and is denoted by $\inf A$ iff:
>
> - $x\ge\beta$ for all $x\in A$
> - if $y$ is a lower bound for $A$, then $y\le \beta$

> The Archimedean property states that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$.

> Equivalently, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n<x$.

Proof:

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose the converse is true, ie., there doesn't exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$. That means, $n\le x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
\begin{align}
&\implies \mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}\text{ is bounded above by }x\\
&\implies \mathbb{N}\text{ has a least upper bound}, \alpha=\sup(\mathbb{N})\in\mathbb{R} \text{ (by the Completeness Axiom)}\\
&\implies \alpha-1<\alpha,\text{ therefore } \alpha-1\text{ is not an upper bound for }\mathbb{N}\\
&\implies \text{There exists }m\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that } \alpha-1<m\le\alpha\\
&\implies \alpha<m+1\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align}
which contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $\mathbb{N}$.

**Lemma 1:** For $\delta>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n}<\delta$

Proof:

Substitute $x=\delta$ in the Archimedean Property, obtains $\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n}<\delta$

---

**Part 2**

> $X\subset Y$ is dense in $Y$ if for any $\delta>0$ and $y\in Y$, there is some $x\in X$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$.

We have to prove that the set $\{\frac{k}{2^n}:k\in\mathbb{W},n\in\mathbb{N},0\le k\le 2^n\}$ of dyadic rationals, ie., numbers with binary expansion in $[0,1]$, are dense in $[0,1]$.

Let's take any $\delta>0$ then from lemma 1 there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n}<\delta$. Let $x\in[0,1]$ and $k=\lfloor x.2^n\rfloor$ correspond to the greatest integer less than or equal to $x.2^n$ such that $0<k\le 2^n$.
\begin{align}
&k=\lfloor x.2^n\rfloor\le x.2^n\le k+1=\lfloor x.2^n\rfloor+1\\
&\implies \frac{k}{2^n}\le x\le \frac{k+1}{2^n}\\
&\implies 0\le x-\frac{k}{2^n}\le \frac{1}{2^n}<\delta \quad\Big(\text{Lemma 1}\Big)
\end{align}
$\therefore$ for any $\delta>0$ and $x\in[0,1]$ there is some $\frac{k}{2^n}\in\{\frac{k}{2^n}:k\in\mathbb{W},n\in\mathbb{N},0\le k\le 2^n\}$ such that $|x-\frac{k}{2^n}|<\delta$

$\implies$ The set $\{\frac{k}{2^n}:k\in\mathbb{W},n\in\mathbb{N},0\le k\le 2^n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$

$\implies$ $I$ is dense in $[0,1]$

Part 1 proves that dyadic rationals are members of $I$, and in part 2 we have proven that the dyadic rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, ie., we can approach any $t\in[0,1]$ by a sequence in our already established $I$ which contains the dyadic rationals. Therefore, the validity of the equations for $t\in[0,1]$ is proven.